# Selenium Python Error

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create a small test program that is able to login into gmail. So far the program opens up the website on chrome but then fails to actually type anything into the "Enter Email" form box. Also I am receiving an error within the shell which may provide insight into my question.

Driver Version: 2.40
Chrome Version: 67.0.3396.99

Below is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver= webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://mail.google.com")
emailid=driver.find_element_by_name("identifier")
emailid.send_keys("samplekeys")
```

Below is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\gmail.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver.get("http://mail.google.com")
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 332, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: missing or invalid 'entry.level'
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("http://mail.google.com")  

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

user_name = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'identifierId')))
user_name.click()
user_name.send_keys("samplekeys")
```

Comment: i don't think that he need to click on element, but try it.

Comment: which error ? because it is running in my system , I am using windows 10 though

Comment: @DrutaRuslan : Yep , no need to click , but I do not see any harm if he clicks it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads), and put the path to your `webdriver.Chrome()`, for example my `chromedriver` are in `/usr/local/bin/chromdriver`

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

or for widndows

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: Ok but I am confused as to how the web page was launched though. If i didn't add the driver location wouldn't the page not even launch?

Comment: i don't know, but for example i can open the `chrome` without `chromedriver`

Comment: can you show your code how do you pass the `chromedriver`?

Comment: Do you think it may have to do with the new chrome not being compatible with he driver?

Comment: can you try to use `'C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe'` ? with double slash

Comment: I changed it to 'C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe' but it produced the same result

Comment: i update answer again, try with `executable_path` if it don't work i will delete my answer ..

Comment: No difference :(

Comment: are you sure that are you passing the lastest `chromedriver`?

Comment: I am on version 2.40